# Under precisely what circumstances is $R\oplus S$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

*Let $R$ and $S$ be rings. Under precisely what circumstances is $R\oplus S$ an integral
domain?*

The definition of integral domain of my book is the following:

> An integral domain is a commutative ring $R$ with identity $1 \neq 0$
> having no zero divisors.

Clearly $R\oplus S$ is a ring, which will be commutative and have identity if and only if $R$ and $S$ are commutative and have identity. But in general, $R\oplus S$ is not a integral domain, since for instance, if $(r,0),(0,s)\in R\oplus S$, with $s,r\neq 0$. $(r,0)(0,s)=(0,0)$ Thus, $R\oplus S$ has zero divisors.

To solve this problem, the only thing I can think of is that either $R$ or $S$ is the zero ring, but what other possibilities are there?

Comment: There are no other possibilities. If you really think about it, you just proved it. And even if one of the rings is zero, the other ring needs to be free of zero divisors.

Answer (score 3):

The ring $R \oplus S$ is an integral domain if and only if either $R$ is an integral domain and $S=0$, or $S$ is an integral domain and $R=0$.